# Can't open VMware after upgrade to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel, vmware

I had Ubuntu 14.10 and vmware 11, after i upgraded my Ubuntu through all releases to 16.04 LTS and all went fine without errors, when i open my vmware gave me :

[image]

Then when i click install it says:

[image]

The log file content is too long, here is number of failed lines:

```
2016-12-22T19:13:35.295+02:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2016-12-22T19:13:35.295+02:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2016-12-22T19:13:35.296+02:00| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2016-12-22T19:13:35.296+02:00| vthread-4| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2016-12-22T19:13:35.373+02:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-12-22T19:13:35.611+02:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-12-22T19:13:35.802+02:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-12-22T19:13:35.819+02:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-12-22T19:13:35.827+02:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-12-22T19:13:35.834+02:00| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/4.4.0-57-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2016-12-22T19:13:38.879+02:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmmon.  Failed to execute the build command.
2016-12-22T19:13:40.623+02:00| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Comment: Try installing latest from the _VMWare_ site

Comment: Do i have to uninstall the current version first, or the new one will complete the missing modules and upgrade?

Comment: Remove the old one first and move the _virtual machines_ you have created so it doesn't get deleted too.

Comment: Now working normally, thanks alot, please reply to the post,

Comment: glad it worked out, and let me an answer so you can mark as accepted one :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1. Download the latest VMWare
2. Move the already created *virtual machines* to another folder
3. Remove the old installed one (VMWare)
4. Install new version.

Hope it helps.